# Getting a value from a form and adding it to another sheet issue

Tags: loops, replace, find

[1]So I have most of the coding working.  Its not pretty but it does sorta work.  What I am trying to do is take form data and then add it to another sheet in cells that are empty.

For instance the form gives 5 serial numbers.  If those serial numbers are not found in the hard count inv sheet I want them to add them in cells for serial numbers 1-10.  I should never have more then 10 serial numbers.

Currently my issue when it adds a serial sometimes it just loops through the same cell and doesnt add to the next cell.  I have added the code below as well as a link to a dummy file.  its set up to be ran without the form at at moment.

this is the logger info I get

```
   [18-08-02 13:11:15:195 PDT] Before If s1 1 s2 2 s3 3 s4  4s5 5
   [18-08-02 13:11:15:196 PDT] Inside Loop s1 1
   [18-08-02 13:11:15:323 PDT] Before If s1 1 s2 2 s3 3 s4  4s5 5 
   [18-08-02 13:11:15:324 PDT] Inside Loop s1 1
   [18-08-02 13:11:16:735 PDT] Before If s1 1 s2 2 s3 3 s4  4s5 5 
   [18-08-02 13:11:16:736 PDT] Inside Loop s1 1
   [18-08 -02 13:11:17:341 PDT] Before If s1 1 s2 2 s3 3 s4  4s5 5 
   [18-08-02 13:11:17:342 PDT] Inside Loop s1 1
   [18-08-02 13:11:18:080 PDT] Before If s1 1 s2 2 s3 3 s4  4s5 5
   [18-08-02 13:11:18:081 PDT] Inside Loop s1 1
```

the code I am looking at is the

AddSerialsToHardCountInvForm
function

[google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KBJvTXkpevj3dQPvyP-_BKA1BJg9krQDj7QwPXxiYGM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have got the code down but for some reason instead of adding the numbers to rows e,f,g,h,i   it always adds it to e.  and uses the last loop value.  Im not sure why its not setting the value on the first loop and then moving to the next column and setting that value and then continuing to the end of the loops..